# How to split the string including the special character

Tags: python, string, split, special-characters

```
string_1 = "\tVH VH VH VL N N N N N N N\n"
```

Here I'm trying to split the string which has a `\t` and `\n` within, when I try to split the string using the `split` function as below:

```
sep_setring = string_1.split()
```

Output:

```
['VH', 'VH', 'VH', 'VL', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N']
```

But, I need an output to be like:

```
['\t', 'VH', 'VH', 'VH', 'VL', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', '\n']
```

Comment: The terse example falls significantly short of a specification. Are the other whitespace characters as `\n` and `\t` also possible in the middle of the string and how to handle them there if bordering a letter or separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `re.findall`:

```py
string_1 = "\tVH VH VH VL N N N N N N N\n"
matches = re.findall(r'\S+|[^\S ]+', string_1)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['\t', 'VH', 'VH', 'VH', 'VL', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', '\n']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern, which alternatively finds a cluster of non whitespace characters or a cluster of whitespace characters (except for space):

```regex
\S+      match one or more non whitespace characters
|        OR
[^\S ]+  match one or more whitespace characters excluding space itself
```

Comment: Another way.  ```re.findall('[\t\n]|\w+', string_1)```

Answer (score 1):

You can split using lookarounds:

```
(?<=\t)|(?=\n)|
```

- `(?<=\t)` Assert a tab to the left
- `|` Or
- `(?=\n)` Assert a newline to the right
- `|` Or
- Match a space

Example

```
import re
string_1 = "\tVH VH VH VL N N N N N N N\n"
sep_setring = re.split(r"(?<=\t)|(?=\n)| ", string_1)
print(sep_setring)
```

Output

```
['\t', 'VH', 'VH', 'VH', 'VL', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', '\n']
```

Comment: Very interesting +1, just learned something new.  Normally `re.split` doesn't accept patterns which only contain lookarounds, but your inclusion of space at the end of the alternation makes it work as we would expect in something like Java or JavaScript.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tested this in Python 2 and you are right about that. I thought this behavior changed in Python 3 from a certain version.